# Integration of Coded ui tests with TFS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I like to use the Coded UI test feature of Visual Studio 2010 but the TFS server we are using is TFS 2008, Is coded ui tests supported by TFS 2008, If yes what i have to do to integrate it with TFS 2008?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

[Coded UI is not supported in TFS 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/vsautotest/thread/cd424ab6-9968-4d2f-8e9b-63476fcc5fff)